# ServiceStack with forms authentication across applications fails...why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, servicestack

I have a ServiceStack project running an API at api.mydomain.com.  An admin project in the same solution is hosted at admin.mydomain.com.  Login/Logout is already handled by the admin application, but I want to make sure the user is authenticated (and sometimes check permissions as well) on my api calls.  I'm using [forms authentication across projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx) so the auth cookie is available to my api project.

Here's my web.config authentication tag in the api project:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms protection="All" loginUrl="home/denied" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="60" defaultUrl="home/denied" path="/" domain="mydomain.com" name=".myAuth"></forms>
</authentication>
```

Based on this [Authentication and authorization post](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization), I added an [Authenticate] attribute to a service method, expecting it to pass/fail based on the value of IsAuthenticated.  However, it redirects to 'home/denied' everytime, regardless of whether the auth cookie is present.  (I confirmed this by subclassing AuthenticateAttribute and examining the OriginalRequest... The cookie set when I logged in using the admin app is present and req.OriginalRequest.IsAuthenticated is true.)

Why is my request being redirected, and how do I properly utilize the existing auth credential set in the admin app?

**EDIT:** Here's the solution I came up with.  It simply requires an IPrincipal Identity to pass authentication.

```
public class AuthenticateAspNetAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute
{
    public override void Execute(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        SessionFeature.AddSessionIdToRequestFilter(req, res, null); //Required to get req.GetSessionId()

        using (var cache = req.GetCacheClient())
        {
            var sessionId = req.GetSessionId();
            var session = sessionId != null ? cache.GetSession(sessionId) : null;
            var originalRequest = (System.Web.HttpRequest) req.OriginalRequest;
            var identity = originalRequest.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity;
            if (!identity.IsAuthenticated)
                AuthProvider.HandleFailedAuth(new BasicAuthProvider(), session, req, res);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the [Authentication and autorization post](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) you reference it reads:

> ServiceStack's Authentication, Caching and Session providers are
>   completely new, clean, dependency-free testable APIs that doesn't rely
>   on and is devoid of ASP.NET's existing membership, caching or session
>   provider models.

Meaning it's completely separate and has nothing to do with the ASP.NET's existing Authentication providers. i.e. The client needs to make an explicit call to the `/auth` service to authenticate with ServiceStack web services.

See the [SocialBootstrapApi](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi) example demo project for an example of an MVC Website that uses and shares ServiceStack's Authentication providers between MVC Controllers and ServiceStack web services.

Comment: Ok, thx. That seems like kind of a bummer...makes the story for adding a new service layer to an existing Asp.Net app a little more complicated. If I understand correctly, I have to re-implement login / authentication using ServiceStack. I've worked through much of SocialBootstrapApi, but that really isn't my situation. Is there a way I could make an adaptor to use the Asp.Net session user?

Comment: Yeah you could make an adapter, it just needs to call the ServiceStack  AuthService internally in the same way the `[Authenticate]` Attribute does with Basic + Digest Auth: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/AuthenticateAttribute.cs#L58

Comment: I didn't do it quite the way you suggested... do you see any problem with this approach?

Comment: That works, tho you're by-passing ServiceStack's authentication and just adding a custom request filter that asserts the user is logged in with ASP.NET auth provider - which does seems like the behavior you want. Since you're not using SS Auth you don't really need the cache or session and can just use these 3 LOC from AuthProvider.HandlFailedAuth: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/AuthProvider.cs#L179-183

Comment: Also I like this approach (of just having a filter to validate ASP.NET Membership Auth) - I'll add this on the TODO list to get something like this inside a future release of ServiceStack :)

Comment: Is there an update to this question that might detail how to do this now?